# Como fazer foreach com Smarty usando Key

Tags: template

Estou fazendo um consulta em meu `BD` para montar uma relação com alguns números de NF e suas respectivas datas, mas o resultado está sendo o último registro, sendo que são três.

O que fiz até agora:

```
  // BUSCANDO DADOS DA AUTORIZAÇÃO
  $this->GetConnection()->ExecQueryToArray('  
SELECT 
  `cadAutorizacaoNF`.NumeroNF,
  `cadAutorizacaoNF`.DataEmissaoNF
FROM
  `cadAutorizacaoNF`
  INNER JOIN `cadAutorizacao` ON (`cadAutorizacaoNF`.IdAutorizacao = `cadAutorizacao`.IdAutorizacao)
WHERE
  (`cadAutorizacaoNF`.IdAutorizacao = '.$IdAutorizacao.')', $queryResultNF);

  $RegistrosNF = array();

  foreach ($queryResultNF as $RegInfNf) {
      $RegistrosNF[$RegInfNf['IdAutorizacao']] = array(
          'NumeroNF' => $RegInfNf['NumeroNF'],
          'DataEmissaoNF' => $RegInfNf['DataEmissaoNF'],  
      );

  }  
  $params['RegistrosNF'] = $RegistrosNF;
```

A minha template que mostra o resultado está assim:

```html
{foreach from=$RegistrosNF item=RegInfNf key=IdAutorizacao}
  <td height="21" align="center">{$RegInfNf.NumeroNF}</td>
  <td height="21" colspan="2" align="center">{if $RegInfNf.DataEmissaoNF != NULL}  {$RegInfNf.DataEmissaoNF|date_format:"%d/%m/%Y"} {else} {/if}</td>
{/foreach}
```

A sintaxe para a chave atual, como especificado no manual do Smarty está assim:

```
$IdAutorizacao = GetApplication()->GetGETValue('pk1');
```